# Google Chrome default console context

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Lately when opening the Google Chrome developer console, the context has been wrong.

I load a page, press Ctrl + Shift + J and get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojr52.png

It changes extensions sometimes but it should be 'top'.

I can change the context manually each time but this is getting kind of annoying to do.

Comment: Can you provide a page where I can reproduce this?

Comment: It happens to me on any page and seems random. It happens on stackoverflow so this page should be fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=613878&can=1&q=Console%20%20top%20status%3DFixed&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) was reported and fixed on the Chromium issue tracker. The revision [#396058](https://codereview.chromium.org/2009903002) has not made it into Chrome stable yet, but you can see that it is fixed in Chrome Canary. It can take 10 weeks for the change to reach the stable version of Chrome, and it has been about 1 month so far.

[image]

### Update (August 15th 2016)

The issue has regressed again and the fix hadn't even reached Chrome stable yet. Another issue has since been logged [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=637618), so we are awaiting a Canary fix, and then a longer wait for Chrome stable. It's very frustrating.

### Update (August 24th 2016)

This seems to be mostly fixed in 54.0.2837.0 (Canary), but I get problems with blank frames on some sites, such as BBC News, Yahoo and MSN. Hopefully this will get looked at (I added a comment on the bug thread), otherwise I'll try and look into a fix myself.

### Update (November 25th 2016)

It's been a while since I last looked at this, but the remaining issues I mentioned in my last update don't exist in Canary 57.0.2931.0, but do in Stable 54.0.2840.98. The issue hasn't been marked as a resolve so don't really know when the fixes took place to track, but I'm sure it wont be long now.

Comment: Thanks very much for letting me know. I might over to Canary in the mean time.

Comment: This bug is still happening to me on Chrome 52.0.2743.82 and 54.0.2813.0 canary MacOS. Example on this page: http://i.imgur.com/O0PrXJf.png

Comment: @fanf Still at revision #394939 in Chrome stable for Windows. Getting close!

Comment: Just to let you guys know, the issue has regressed in Canary so we are back to waiting for a new fix!

Comment: Still buggy in Chrome 52.0.2743.116 OS X

Comment: @Gideon it's October, and still having this same issue. My chrome version is up to date: Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)