# Why is jQuery not being loaded in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Steps to reproduce this behaviour:

Step 1 - access this page using Google Chrome (without dev tools open): http://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com/star-trek-planetary-glassware-set/

Step 2 - run `$.fn.jquery` in the console. It says that jQuery does not exist.

Step 3 - Refresh the page and run `$.fn.jquery` again on the console. jQuery now exists.

Do you know why this happens? jQuery is being requested in the `<head>` in both cases. I can't reproduce this in any other browser, incognito or with the Chrome dev tools open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you are running the command on the correct context:

[image: Chrome Extension Context]

[image: Top]

There is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=613878&can=1&q=Console%20%20top%20status%3DFixed&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) in Chrome that is setting the context incorrectly when DevTools opens. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38054309/1814840) for details on the status. Right now it is fixed in Canary but not yet in Chrome stable.

Comment: Is the chrome bug fixed for you? For me it still isn't