# Can only access variable of dynamically added JS in browser console after reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, scope, console

```html
<script id="jsfile" data-id="1" type="text/javascript" src="http://reichjohannes.com/console.js"></script>
```

In my HTML-file I have a script added like this:

```
<script id="jsfile" data-id="1" type="text/javascript" src="http://website/path/to/another/script/file.js"></script>
```

That script which is loaded gets itself and the data-id value and stores it in a variable. After 2 seconds it console.logs the variable value. So far this is working.

```
var currentScript = document.currentScript || document.getElementById("jsfile"),
    dataId = currentScript.getAttribute("data-id");

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(dataId);
    console.log("Done!");
}, 2000);
```

When I now want to access that variable via the Chrome console, I get an error message that "dataId" is not defined. When I reload the page, it will console log the "dataId" value again and suddenly I can acess the variable from the console.

Why is that and how can it be fixed to make the variable accessible from the start?

Comment: If the script you've quoted above has run, `dataId` will be accessible from the console provided you're not running into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002591/google-chrome-default-console-context). If you're seeing a delay, I suspect it's caused by something you're not showing. Put a **runnable** [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) and say what specific version of Chrome you're seeing this behavior in.

Comment: Not sure if that is what you meant but I added this script. You can run the code and get the variables logged in the console. However, you cannot log/access the variable again in the console. Unfortunately you cannot reload the page here. So I've uploaded an html-file where it can be reproduced http://reichjohannes.com/console.html

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Questions on SO must be self-contained. You can simulate downloading a JavaScript file by putting **only** the necessary code in the `script` tag inline.

Comment: Many thanks for your support, but I am lost... don't know what I have to do to get this "working" here... :/